# What exactly does edge loop selection do?

Tags: selection-tools

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> — What exactly does it do? After subdivisions or loop cuts, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> does not seem to select some loops.

What should one do to define a loop? How can I use select edge loops efficiently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An Edge Loop is a chain of connected edges where each edges shares a vertex with the previous edge, and that vertex has exactly 4 edges attached to it (except on the borders of a non-manifold (not "water-tight") mesh, where there will be only 3 edges, 2 of which have just one face connected).

An edge loop is *terminated* where the vertex has more than 4 edges (poles) or meets a non-manifold edge (an edge with only one face) or an Ngon (face with more than 4 verts). The latitudinal loops (*rings*) of a UV sphere are perfect non-terminating loops, but the longitudinal loops (*segments*) all end at two points (the North and South poles)

Here are some examples of edge loops (see where they change direction or terminate and why)

[image: Simple]

[image: S-shape]

[image: P-shape]

Details on the algorithm from the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting/Edges):

> - First check to see if the selected element connects to only 3 other edges.
> - If the edge in question has already been added to the list, the selection ends.
> - Of the 3 edges that connect to the current edge, the ones that share a face with the current edge are eliminated and the remaining edge is added to the list and is made the current edge.

Answer (score 6):

There is no option to tell Blender, that something is an edge loop. An edge loop is defined by the topology of your mesh. It is a loop consisting of edges.

From Wikipedia:

> An edge loop, in computer graphics, can loosely be defined as a set of connected edges across a surface. Usually the last edge meets again with the first edge, thus forming a loop. The set or string of edges can for example be the outer edges of a flat surface or the edges surrounding a 'hole' in a surface.

See Blender Wiki for more details: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting/Edges

Comment: That link is useful, but this is currently an essentially link-only answer...

Comment: You're right. I put more info into the answer.