# Loop cut entirely after dissolving an edge

Tags: modeling

I can still cut it entirely with the Loop cut.

[image]

Thing is, I want to get rid of that edge, I do that by dissolving it:

[image]

Now here's the problem, after that, I can't cut it entirely. I've also tried dissolving the remaining vertices but it didn't work.

[image]

So what I want to do is to cut it entirely after dissolving the edge, instead of doing it separately as you can see in the pic. Is there a way to achieve that? Did I make a wrong move?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7990/599

Comment: If you look at the menu, there is also 'Edge Loop',  it's the one I always use since it also removes the extra vertices as well as the edge.  That doesn't answer your question but I think it may be useful to you nonetheless .

Answer (score 3):

You can not use the Loop Cut tool because you have an n-gon (face with more than 4 vertices, in your case 5) on the top.

The Loop Cut tool only works with quads (faces with 4 vertices).

First use **Dissolve Edges** then immediately after use **Dissolve Vertices**; Or update to the newest version and use **Dissolve Edges and Vertices**.

Answer (score 1):

A great solution to reconnect those edges without is using the join function <kbd>J</kbd>, or the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd>. You can do things differently, but if you have already made the cut, these tools offer a quick way to fix the issue. If there are no edges, between the vertices, you can use the join tool.

The join tool works in cases where there is no edge between the to vertices. 
*Will Work* --------------------------------------------------- *Will Not Work*

[image]
[image]

To use the join tool, select to two vertices you wan't to join, and hit <kbd>J</kbd>. In cases where you can't use the join tool, use the kinfe tool. hit <kbd>K</kbd>. Left click on the two vertices you want to join and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.