# Loopcut not creating

Tags: modeling

So if you look a the image I extruded the side and filled a face at top, the bottom is empty and I wanted to create a loop around the 3 sides but it will only appear for one side any tips. [image]

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/why-does-loop-cut-and-slide-ignore-some-faces-but-not-others

Comment: Have you tried pressing *W* > *remove doubles*

Comment: That worked thanks, is there any signs I can look out for to know I have a double.

Comment: I have not really paid super close attention to what makes double vertices.  I think they are just artifacts of some algorithms, when ever I have peculiar things like this happening I usually try removing doubles first.  If that doesn't work the problem is probably n-gons or non-manifold geometry (see the question stacker linked).