# Is it possible to add a loop cut and slide like this

Tags: modeling

I am try to make a model of a knife, and i am using the loop cut and slide option.
this is what i managed to do before i ran into a little problem

[image]

now i want to make it so that the purple line that appears when i click on the loop cut and slide option is rotate by 90 so that i can place it like this
[image: http://prntscr.com/6qbno4]

i am using a plane mesh to which i added some thickness

Comment: You probably have polygons with more than 4 sides. Loop cuts will only work with quads.

Comment: and how can i fix that ?

Comment: Exactly what **Cegaton** said, because that is a current feature, I use it all the time. If you have "N-Gons" or "Tris" (faces with more or less edges than a quad). You may need to re-model your mesh, or maybe you can repair the specific face by dissolving it and trying to re-connect (Delete > Faces then F to connect)

Comment: i found this could this be the problem ?
http://prntscr.com/6qc4bw

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: :/ idk how to fix this then, i dont even know what some of the thing you said are, like "face with more or less edges than a quad" not sure what a quad is

Comment: A quad = a quadrilateral, or, a face with 4 sides (edges).

Comment: Maybe he is moussing over the wrong portion of the mesh, no?

Comment: @TheGreen627 have you tried moving your cursor to different positions?

Comment: see id either of these questions help [why does loop-cut-and-slide ignore some faces but not others](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7990/2217) or [Loop-cut won't go all the way around](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17870/2217)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you have a triangular face there.
[image: your situation]

Just make it quadratic and the edge loop would work.
[image]