# Some areas won't let me loop cut?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges

I'm having a few issues with Blender..
1. I'm trying to make a loop cut in this area:
[image]

But it won't let me make a loop cut there! There are other areas that I want to do loop cuts as well. I noticed in certain areas if I dissolved edges, I wasn't able to make loop cuts there anymore. How can I fix this?

2. I am trying to move a specific vertices, but it's doing this:
   [image]

How can I move it to where I want to if that happens?

Comment: you only can make a loop cut in a quadrilateral face (4 edges)

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/why-does-loop-cut-and-slide-ignore-some-faces-but-not-others

Comment: Thanks for those topics Mr Zak. I'm new to the site and hadn't seen them. Using the knife tool works to create that loop cut once it has 4 edges.

Comment: Why is that 2nd thing happening though?

Comment: If you mean part of the question related to the 2nd screenshot then it's another question (which should be posted separately) and at the moment not clear one (did you want to move selected vertex or did you actually move it, what is not as expected etc). Anyway it's another question..