# Loop Cut & Slide wont work over a face

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

So I am trying to make a building in Blender for my University Project. I have made the outside of the building and now I am trying to add windows with frames at the front. One side of my building has a window, which I created with no issues. Now I am trying to clone this on the other side of the building I am finding that the loop cut keeps skipping a face of my window for some reason, and I can't figure out why! I have a few screenshots (https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1fDA.jpg) and hopefully, this shows what I mean. Any help would be appreciated.

Side note, this is my first ever time using Blender so I am not aware of many of the shortcuts etc.

EDIT: Here is my blend file: *Removed, can be readded if needed. Don't want my work being flagged up when I upload it.*

Thanks

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]

Comment: maybe Knife or Knife Project would be a better option https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html#knife-project

Comment: There are either zero-area faces (visible dot indicating face between other faces) and / or Ngons in the area where loopcut breaks. If selecting all and removing doubles doesn't help select those manually and delete faces

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/why-does-loop-cut-and-slide-ignore-some-faces-but-not-others

Comment: .. and since your building is largely symmetrical, it _might_ save you work, if the (-Y) side is OK, to  temporarily keep a copy of the asymmetrical element on the roof, complete the seam at Y=0, V > rip it, delete the (+Y) side, and mirror the whole building left to right.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will try all these solutions, hopefully one works.