Loop cuts not making it all the way round

Hi,
I am trying to make loop cuts that connect to the verteces around the top of the stairs (to fix n-gons), but the loop cut seems to stop at an arbitrary place. Do you know why this might be?
Also, does my stairs topology look ok? This is my first time modelling and all I know is that I should try to avoid n-gons.

It stops whenever it finds a face that does not have exactly 4 sides or is not connected to the next face. You should review your topology

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/why-does-loop-cut-and-slide-ignore-some-faces-but-not-others https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around
